# how to fix an adobe edge html5 animation that restarts the loop before animation completes in live browser?

Tags: html, animation, loops, joomla, adobe-edge

I have put together an animated banner ad with Edge Animate and embedded it within my website. When the looped ad plays, it finishes pre-maturely, then starts at the begining again. Each time the ad plays, abit more of the animation plays out before it stops and starts again. For example, the 1st play through may get to the 22 seconds of the 30 second ad. Then the 2nd it will make it to 27 second. Eventually the whole ad will play after maybe 4 times.

The preview within Edge and in the browser always loops correctly. Its only when the ad is embedded in the website.

The code I've used is super simple, and what I suspect might be the problem (I'm super sorry if this is a noob/obvious-solution problem, I'm not a coder at all )

sym.play(0);

That Trigger is placed at the 30 second mark on the timeline, which is when i want the ad to loop obviously.

Its being embedded with iframe on a joomla website. And I am using the latest Edge Animate release. The entire file size of the published ad is roughly 512kb.

Does anyone has a vauge idea of why its looping incorrectly?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since it works the way you want it to in the preview and in a browser, the problem would seem to be with the embedding.

apparently, there are a lot of problems when using adobe edge with joomla.
you might try no-conflict mode as suggested here:

http://www.search-friendly-web-design.com/general/72-playing-with-adobe-edge-and-getting-the-output-into-a-joomla-site

another option would be to manually add the components of your edge composition (including links to js files) to your html file.